# Why doesn't this generate duplicate symbols for linker?

Tags: c++, linker, c++14

Let's assume the following code:

```
// IInterface.h

#pragma once

class IInterface
{
  public:
  struct Thing
  {
    // If i uncomment this line, I can see that all object files increase in size.
    // char data[10240];
    int getOne() { return 1;}
  };
  // The interface doesn't really matter
};
```

---

```
// Derived1.h
#pragma once
#include "IInterface.h"

class Der1: public IInterface
{
  public:
  int getOne();
};
```

---

```
// Derived2.h
#pragma once
#include "IInterface.h"

class Der2: public IInterface
{
  public:
  int getOne();
};
```

---

```
// Derived1.cpp
#include "Derived1.h"

int Derived1::getOne()
{
  Thing thing;
  return thing.getOne();
}
```

---

```
// Derived2.cpp
#include "Derived2.h"

int Derived2::getOne()
{
  Thing thing;
  return thing.getOne();
}
```

---

```
// main.cpp

// Not really needed I guess?

#include "Derived1.h"
#include "Derived2.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Der1 der1;
  Der2 der2;

  return der1.getOne() - der2.getOne();
}
```

Now I'm not sure how to put this question to words, but here I go.

Why doesn't the method IInterface::Thing::getOne generate linker errors because it has multiple versions of it in different translation units?

If I made a version where getOne is just a global function declared and defined in IInterface.h, that would generate linker errors.

I know I could move the struct to a separate .cpp file, but since it's IInterface and I'm using C++17, I don't need a .cpp file. There isn't one.

Oh and I'm on MSVC 2019. But I'm interested if this code works for GCC, or other compilers. I'll have to run some tests.

Comment: Compiler generates weak symbols for template functions and templated class members. During linking, multiple weak symbols are allowed. I wrote [article about that](https://gudok.xyz/inline/).

Comment: Ok, I'll read that. But this is not a template though, and why isn't the function allowed?

Comment: Ok, it seems that your article provides some good information. It just makes me wonder why things are the way they are, but that isn't so important anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the excellent article by [gudok](https://gudok.xyz/inline/), which you should read too if you aren't familiar, makes me now see what happens.

So the thing is that the method Thing::getOne is inlined by default (because it's defined and declared in the header). Inlined but not expanded methods are marked for weak linking. And that's the end of that.

Comment: If someone wants to write a better answer go ahead and I'll mark it as the answer.